# Python PySimpleGUI & time.sleep(): how to wait for condition to be met without freezing GUI?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, sleep, pysimplegui

I am learning about making a GUI in Python, with the goal of eventually using a GUI to operate some devices in my laboratory.  I am having a problem with telling the GUI to wait for a condition to be met.

I tried first to use a while loop like this

```
while i < some_limit:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i) 
    i+=1

#in the actual code this will be sending a query to a measurement device at regular intervals, e.g. to see whether it has finished conducting a measurement
```

After doing some reading I found that apparently it is time.sleep() that is causing the GUI to freeze, and one way to avoid the issue is to use threads.

Here is an example code of what I have now:

```
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def side_thread(limit):
    i=0
    while i<=limit:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    return 

layout = [
            [sg.Text('current state:'), sg.Text(key='-STATE_OUT-')],
            [sg.Text('limit'), sg.Input(key='-LIMIT-', s=5)],
            [sg.Button('start counting')]
        ]

window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'start counting':
        timelimit = float(values['-LIMIT-'])
        
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count starting')

        c_thread = threading.Thread(target=side_thread, kwargs={'limit': timelimit})
        c_thread.start()
        
        # if side thread has returned then continue
        
        c_thread.join()
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count finished')
```

What I want to happen is this following sequence:

1. I press the 'start counting' button
2. The text 'current state: count starting'  appears
3. The program starts counting until the limit is reached, preferably without freezing the GUI
4. the text 'current state: count finished' appears

but what currently happens is that when I press the button, the GUI window immediately freezes (the text 'count starting' does not appear) until the while loop has finished, then the text 'count finished' appears.

I have also tried using window.TKroot.after()

```
window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'start counting':
        timelimit = float(values['-LIMIT-'])
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count starting')
        
        i=0
        while i<timelimit:
            window.TKroot.after(1000)
            print(i)
            i+=1
        
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count finished')
```

but I still get the same problem.

EDIT: Follow up to Jason Yang's answer

Is it possible to implement write_event_value inside a for loop?

For example I have:

```
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
            [sg.Text('Counting Sequence')],
            [sg.Text('current progress'), sg.Text(key='-PR_OUT-')],
            [sg.Text('repeat count'), sg.Text(key='-RC_OUT-')],
            [sg.Text('set repeat count'), sg.Input(key='-Set_RC-', s=10)],
            [sg.Button('start sequence')]
        ]


def sequence_thread(limit):
    i=0
    while i<=limit:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    return

window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    
    if event == 'start sequence':
        endpoint = int(values['-Set_RC-'])
        window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence starting')

        for i in range(endpoint):
            c_thread = threading.Thread(target=sequence_thread, args=(3,))
            c_thread.start()
            c_thread.join()
            rep_count = i+1
            window['-RC_OUT-'].update(str(rep_count))
        
        window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence finished')


window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Main thread blocked at `c_thread.join()`, so GUI show no response.

Using method `window.write_event_value` to generate an event to main thread to update GUI.

```py
import time
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def side_thread(window, limit):
    i=0
    while i<=limit:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    window.write_event_value('counting done', None)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('current state:'), sg.Text(key='-STATE_OUT-')],
    [sg.Text('limit'), sg.Input(key='-LIMIT-', s=5)],
    [sg.Button('start counting')]
]

window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing',layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == 'start counting':
        timelimit = float(values['-LIMIT-'])
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count starting')
        c_thread = threading.Thread(target=side_thread, args=(window, timelimit), daemon=True)
        c_thread.start()

    elif event == 'counting done':
        window['-STATE_OUT-'].update('count finished')

window.close()
```

Of course, `for loop` under your event loop is OK, but don't take much time before you back to statement `window.read()`. Update GUI in your for loop is required, call `window.refresh()` to update the GUI, or it will show last result only.

Again, don't call `c_thread.join()`, or it will be blocked here. To update GUI, you can call `window.write_event_value` to generate an event anywhere. you can keep all threads in a list and monitor the `end` event to confirm if all threads finished before you close window and quit.

In following code, the GUI update in the `for` loop is too quick, so you cannot find the change. Add one statement, `sleep(1)` to slow down the GUI.

```py
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
            [sg.Text('Counting Sequence')],
            [sg.Text('current progress'), sg.Text(key='-PR_OUT-')],
            [sg.Text('repeat count'), sg.Text(key='-RC_OUT-')],
            [sg.Text('set repeat count'), sg.Input(key='-Set_RC-', s=10)],
            [sg.Button('start sequence')]
        ]


def sequence_thread(window, index, limit):
    i=0
    while i <= limit:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    window.write_event_value('Done', index)

window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing',layout)
threads = []

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == 'start sequence':
        endpoint = int(values['-Set_RC-'])
        window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence starting')
        for i in range(endpoint):
            c_thread = threading.Thread(target=sequence_thread, args=(window, i, 3), daemon=True)
            c_thread.start()
            threads.append(i)
            window['-RC_OUT-'].update(i)
            window.refresh()
            # time.sleep(1)

    elif event == 'Done':
        i = values[event]
        threads.remove(i)
        if not threads:
            window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence finished')

window.close()
```

For sequence threads, IMO, one thread for all of them should be OK.

```py
import threading
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(limit):
    i=0
    while i <= limit:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

def sequence_thread(window, endpoint, limit):
    for i in range(endpoint):
        window.write_event_value('Step', i+1)
        func(limit)
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Counting Sequence')],
    [sg.Text('current progress'), sg.Text(key='-PR_OUT-')],
    [sg.Text('repeat count'), sg.Text(key='-RC_OUT-')],
    [sg.Text('set repeat count'), sg.Input(key='-Set_RC-', s=10)],
    [sg.Button('start sequence')]
]
window = sg.Window('thread and GUI testing', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == 'start sequence':
        endpoint = int(values['-Set_RC-'])
        window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence starting')
        threading.Thread(target=sequence_thread, args=(window, endpoint, 3)).start()

    elif event == 'Step':
        i = values[event]
        window['-RC_OUT-'].update(i)

    elif event == 'Done':
        window['-PR_OUT-'].update('sequence finished')

window.close()
```

Comment: I'd like to ask, will it become an issue if the side thread is not closed? Also is there a way to update the GUI inside the 'start counting' event itself? Asking because I will eventually need the GUI to do a sequence of such waiting loops, not just once.

Comment: Better with code to demo new questions.

Comment: updated as above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the for loop how to ensure that one thread starts only after the previous one has finished? In my terminal the program is printing something like 012013021323 instead of the expected 012301230123 .

Comment: Should post your question for all requirements, otherwisee, it will a new question again and again after old one replied. It waste time for you and I. For threads, there maybe won't be executed in same order. Updated.